# Geometric imports

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

In a theorem of mobius transformation, we have to prove that every mobius transformation is the resultant of mobius transformations with simple geometric imports. What is the meaning of simple geometric imports here?

Comment: Never heard this word 'inport" in this context, though I know the domain...

Comment: Honestly I have never heard of it, but I managed to find [this old book](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.133830), in which such terminology is used (even if I haven't found a precise definition): see page 133, section 5.12

Comment: @dario thanks for helping

Comment: @jeanmarie thanks for replying